# usage of socket.io in the production environment?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Sever-side code:

```
import * as socket from 'socket.io';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
});

var io = socket.listen(server); 
 io.on('connection', socket => {

     //other  code
  });
```

Client-side code:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

// So far this works in localhost without any issues
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { transports: ['websocket'] });

// For production does the below code works
var socket = io('https://mydomainname', { transports: ['websocket'] });
```

Can any help me here. how to use this in production?

Comment: What is your actual question? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How do I use this in production. Do I need to pass my domain name as shown in example. var socket = io('https://mydomainname', { transports: ['websocket'] });

Comment: You pass an http url to `io()` just like you were doing in your test code.  You don't pass just the domain.  Pass a whole http URL.  Also, please edit your question to state what the question is.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your response. var socket = io( 'https://www.awsloadbalancingomk.ga' ); is this the right way of usage?

Comment: The formatting didn't come out in your comment, but I think you intended it right: `var socket = io('https://www.awsloadbalancingomk.ga/');`

Comment: Even I have added my domain as specified above I am still getting error in WebSocket connection to 'wss://test.commoncollection.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301.